# DUMPBIN utility mangled name output

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I am using DUMPBIN utility for getting mangled name from a c++ dll to use in a c# application .
I am exposing a c++ class member function using __declspec(dllexport) and the output mangled name result is the folowing

```
?InitPort@CProtocolStack@@QAEEHEPAEKE@Z = ?InitPort@CProtocolStack@@QAEEHEPAEKE@Z (public: unsigned char __thiscall CProtocolStack::InitPort(int,unsigned char,unsigned char *,unsigned long,unsigned char))
```

Do I need to use the whole name in C# application while importing the same function ?
If not, which part will be sufficient for importing?

Comment: It is an instance method of a C++ class.  You cannot pinvoke them, a C++/CLI wrapper is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need this bit:

```
?InitPort@CProtocolStack@@QAEEHEPAEKE@Z
```

Then you declare it something like:

```
[DllImport("your.dll",
    EntryPoint = "?InitPort@CProtocolStack@@QAEEHEPAEKE@Z",
    ExactSpelling = true)]
static extern byte CProtocolStack::InitPort( /* etc. */);
```

Comment: @JamesKanze Very true, but in the meantime, we do what we can... COM might be a better interop option.

Comment: Declare the functions `extern "C"`, so the name won't be mangled.

Comment: @JamesKanze I thought `extern "C"` didn't apply to class member functions.

Comment: It doesn't.  You have to provide interface wrapper functions.  But C# class member functions can be implemented with and `extern "C"` function in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Don't.  If you're not using managed C++ (which can be called
directly from C#), declare the functions in your interface
`extern "C"`, then use the function name directly.  Mangling can
change from one version of the compiler to the next; the `extern
"C"` names won't.

Answer (score 0):

If your function does not need to be overloaded, you can use `extern "C"` for determining the name of the function.